# Move an element within its sibling using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to move an image within "p" element in the following html:

```
<div class="entery-post-excerpts">
<p>content1</p>
<a href="#" class="alignrightthumb"><img width="210" height="158" src="http://imageurl"></a>
</div>
```

Result:

```
<div class="entery-post-excerpts">
<p>content1<a href="#" class="alignrightthumb"><img width="210" height="158" src="http://imageurl"></a></p>
</div>
```

I tried the following script:

```
$('.alignrightthumb').each(function() {
$(this).appendTo($(this).parent().chidlren('p:first-child'));
});
```

OR

```
$('.alignrightthumb').each(function() {
$(this).appendTo($(this).siblings('p'));
});
```

It seems it does not work... How can I make it done?

Comment: So what is your issue? want to know which one is better?

Comment: @Rajaparbhu. Sorry for the confusion. I edited my question. It seems it does not work. Are there any errors in my script?

Comment: Your code should work. https://jsfiddle.net/12ojm3ps/

Comment: @Peter Can you describe _"it does not work"_ ?

Comment: @Rajaparbhu. I found that there was a minor error (a quote missing) in my html code. Now it works as expected. Thanks for your help.